# Prove by induction: $1(1!)+\cdots + n\cdot n!$ = (n+1)! - 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Induction step.
$1(1!) + ... + n(n!) = (n+1)!  - 1$ 
$1(1!) + ... + n(n!) + (n+1)(n+1)! = (n+1)! - 1 + (n+1)(n+1)!$ 
So, I don't understand how to get $(n+2)! - 1$ from $(n+1)! - 1 + (n+1)(n+1)!$.
Please, explain it step by step.

Comment: $$1\cdot (n+1)! - 1 + (n+1)\cdot (n+1)! = (n+2)\cdot (n+1)! - 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Do some factoring:
\begin{align*}
(n+1)!−1+(n+1)(n+1)!
&= [(n+1)(n+1)! + 1(n+1)!] - 1 \\
&= [(n+1) + 1](n + 1)! - 1 \\
&= (n + 2)(n + 1)! - 1 \\
&= (n + 2)! - 1 \\
\end{align*}

Comment: How we get **1** on the first line?

Comment: And on the third line how to multiply parentheses?

Comment: I used the fact that $(n + 1)! = 1 \cdot (n + 1)!$. For the third line, I used a property of factorials. For example, note that $7! = (7)6! = (7)(6)5!$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ the equality is trivial:
$$ 1(1!)=1 =(1+1)!-1$$
Then, we have the basis of induction.

Now, supose that the equality is true for $n=k$, i.e.,
$$1(1!)+...k(k!)=(k+1)!-1 .    (*)$$

We need to show that is true for $n=k+1$, i.e.,
$$1(1!)+...+(k+1)(k+1)!=(k+2)!-1. $$
Indeed, summing $(k+1)(k+1)!$ in (*) we obtain
$$1(1!)+...+k(k!)+(k+1)(k+1)!=(k+1)!-1+(k+1)(k+1)!=(k+1)![1+(k+1)]-1=$$
$$=(k+1)![k+2]-1 =(k+2)!-1 .$$

So, the result follows by the principle of mathematical induction.